# video doesn't render on page(html5 video tag)

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, video, rendering

I am trying to render video file on the page.

I have wrote following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/member/createCompany/getVideo/{contentId}.flv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("contentId") String fileName) {
        return new FileSystemResource(new File("D:\\video.flv"));
    }
```

and on the page I have wrote following html:

```
<video src="/member/createCompany/getVideo/1.flv" controls="">
</video>
```

But after it looks like this:

[image]

But I when I click "play" nothing happens.

As you can see on screenshot, controller sucessfully returns response(status 200)

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

looks like a problem with format. I tried to load another movie and this works. But one more movie plays only sound.

Hmm... html5 video tag is too whimsical with format.

Answer (score 0):

flv files are Flash, which HTML5 video does not support, you need to have it converted to a file type that is supported such as MP4 or WebM.

Comment: Is there analog of html5 to play all popular formats?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: html5 is not suitable for my situation because bad supports video formats. Can you advice something for me?

Comment: HTML5 does not have bad support for video formats at all, but you want it to play Flash so I suggest that you simply embed it with the object element.

Comment: Then your MP4 file is possibly not in the correct format. Sadly there are many different flavours of MP4 file. Try converting it using the free Miro Video Converter?

Comment: I write site. Site has posibility to upload video. I want to support all popular formats. After uploading video I should to show it on the page.

Comment: Then you probably need to write code that will check the format of the video and use whatever method is best for the uploaded video in question.

Comment: How to check that mp4 is H.264 ?